# GraphQL nested query returning null field

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to learn GraphQL (& node.js & MongoDB etc.). I cant get this simple nested query to return results :

```
query getLocationByPerson {
   People {
        firstName
        lastName
        service {
        location
      }
   }
}
```

I only get the first level fields, like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "People": [
      {
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "lastName": "XXXXX",
        "service": null
      }
}
```

Here's my schema:

```
type Query {
  People: [PeopleObject]!
  PeopleByName(lastName: String!): [PeopleObject]
  PeopleByID(id:ID!): [PeopleObject]
  Service: [ServiceObject]
  ServiceByID(id:ID!): [ServiceObject]
}
type PeopleObject {
    id: ID!
    Xid: String!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
    serviceId: String
    apps: [String]
    service: [ServiceObject]
}
type ServiceObject {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    location: String!
}
```

And my resolver:

```
const queries = {
    People: () => People.find({}),
    PeopleByName: (root,args,context,info) => People.find({lastName: args.lastName}),
    PeopleByID: (root,args,context,info) => People.find({_id: args.id}),
    Service: () => Service.find({}),
    ServiceByID: (root,args,context,info) => Service.find({_id: args.id})
  };
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reference for the location object in service which is same as you mongoose model(i assume you are using mongoose). After passing the reference you can add populate(refernce).exec() in your service query [Refer this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: thanks, but as a total noob I would ask :  can you please post a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax are dame good for getting any data from graphql

```
type Query {
  People: [PeopleObject]!
}
type PeopleObject {
    id: ID!
    Xid: String!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
    serviceId: String
    apps: [String]
    service: [ServiceObject]
}
type ServiceObject {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    location: String!
}
```

for Simplicity

```
type Query {
  People: [{
    id: ID!
    Xid: String!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
    serviceId: String
    apps: [String]
    service: [{
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        location: String!
    }]
}]!
}
```

But you have return only people

```
People: () => People.find({}),
```

You should return service array object to get that return object with People

`People: () =>`  return something Like below result.

```
[{
    id: '5c5ac87e5e4d85ae77de9c50'
    Xid: 'xx'
    firstName: 'yyy'
    lastName: 'zzz'
    email: 'xxx@gmail.com'
    serviceId: '5c5ac87e5e4d85ae77de9c51'
    apps: ['testing', 'google']
    service: [{
        id: 5c5ac78d5e4d85ae77de9c4f,
        name: 'Tester',
        location: 'US America',
    }, {}]
}, {}]
```

If you using mongoose use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to get data from mongoBD.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you help me to implement aggregation, I dont get it.

Comment: I'm so sorry, what do you mean by "modal of person and service"?

Comment: people.js:
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const peopleSchema = new Schema({
    Xid: { type: String },
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    apps: { type: Array },
    serviceId: { type: String }
},{ versionKey: false })

module.exports = mongoose.model('people', peopleSchema);`

Comment: service.js
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const serviceSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    location: { type: String }
},{ versionKey: false })

module.exports = mongoose.model('service', serviceSchema);`

Comment: For agregation or populate you must have reference to make relationship
serviceId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'service' },

Comment: people.js is now :
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const peopleSchema = new Schema({
    Xid: { type: String },
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    apps: { type: Array },
    serviceId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'service' }
},{ versionKey: false })

module.exports = mongoose.model('people', peopleSchema);`

but still got null result for location field on my query :(

Comment: People: async() => {
 const peoples = await People.aggregate({
{ $lookup: { from: 'service', localField: 'serviceId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'service'} }})
return peoples
}

Comment: still dont get how to implement this code. I've put everything in a github repository : https://github.com/fabricezerrouki/graphql-playground
Would you mind to edit whats needed, could be easier for you to help me that way. Thank you so much

Comment: pull requests created

Comment: I updated the repository with the last modifications I made thanks to you, but still not working :(